# Easiest way to make Rails RESTful routes for this setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I want to have the following routes resolve:

```
splunk/ocd/:some_number
splunk/ord/:some_number
```

I want these to be handled by the `ocd`, `ord` functions in `SplunkController`. What's the easiest way to create these routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, since it is not following crud.

```
get 'splunk/ocd/:some_number' => "splunk#ocd", as: 'splunk_ocd'
get 'splunk/ord/:some_number' => "splunk#ord", as: 'splunk_ord'
```